# Validating masked credit card number with regex in Jest

Tags: javascript, regex, jestjs

I'm trying to use regex using the `match` function in Jest.

I have a value where the card number is masked with the character `X` 9 times.

I want to make sure that the `X` in the value occurs 9 times and not any more or less times.

Not sure if its my regEx is wrong or my understanding of `match` in Jest.

For example:

```
test("cardNumber should be masked XXXXXXXXX", () => {
    const val = 'XXXXXXXXX1111';
    const regX = new RegExp(/([X]{9})/);
    expect(val).toMatch(regX);
});
```

Comment: Your understanding of strings is wrong.

Comment: Would you care to explain ?

Comment: What happens when you run this test? Do you see any errors or failure information?

Comment: apsillers It passes even if I remove some of the X's which it should not. If I remove 1 of the X's it should not pass.

Comment: I can't see how that's possible -- or do you mean if you take away any `X` from the test regex (e.g., `X{8}`)? I could see *adding* an `X` to the input as a problem (since a string with 10 `X`s also does have 9 `X`s as well). Does the `X` run always come at the beginning? If so, `/^X{9}[^X]*$/` will do: that's "9 `X`s at the beginning of the string followed by zero or more not-`X` values through the end of the string." Will there only ever be `X`s and numbers? If so, `/^\d*X{9}\d*$/` will do: "any amount of digits, then 9 `X`s, then any amount of digits"

Comment: apsilllers this was what I was after. Thanks again /^\d*X{9}\d*$/. If you want to add it as a solution so I can vote you up.

Comment: /^X{9}[^X]*$/ this would have worked also thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that this is unrelated to Jest, but it's good that you provided context just in case.

A few problems/misunderstandings with the regex pattern, some cosmetic and one not:

`[X]` is the same as `X`. Brackets in regex patterns denote a character group (match *any* of the characters within the group) and there's no need for that here.

`()` creates a capturing group, and there's no need for that either since we just want a yes/no answer of whether the string matched.

Given that, we can simplify the pattern to `/X{9}/` which matches strings that contain 9 sequential `X` characters anywhere in the string. So this will match the string `"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1111"` and `"foobar XXXXXXXXX quux"`, and these are false positives per your specification.

Although your specification isn't entirely clear, the fix is likely to use anchors, based on the follow-up comments. `/^X{9}\d{4}$/` seems most precise, specifying exactly nine `X` characters followed by exactly 4 digits with the front and rear of strings anchored with `^` and `$` respectively. You could relax it with, say, `/^X{9}\d+$/` to use one or more digits.

As an aside, you don't need to use the `new RegExp` constructor here. The direct regex literal is cleaner:

```
expect(val).toMatch(/^X{9}\d{4}$/);
```